# WordPress : Loop data into array for WP_meta_query

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to make a loop to create a request WP_meta_query (source : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) but I have hard time to get the expected result.

Here is the context : People can sarch for posts in the search form. I also had custom fields on the posts via the magic-field-2 plugin. When the people search, they can write something and check some checkboxes to get a more accurate result.

The easiest way I found to manage this is to extract data from the search and do a WP_meta_query to find what I need.

The actual syntax for this kind of search looks like this :

```
query_args = array( 'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'foo_key',
        // 'value' => 'foo',
        // 'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'bar_key',
    ),
) );
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query();
$meta_query->parse_query_vars( $query_args );
$mq_sql = $meta_query->get_sql(
    'post',
    $wpdb->posts,
    'ID',
    null
);
```

As I told in my topic, I'm trying to loop from my search results and recreate a similar array.

First, I splited the array in two.

```
Array ( [s] => John ) 
Array ( [enseignant] => on [travailleur] => on )
```

The search term in one and my checkboxes in the other. As You can see, I search John in "enseignant" and "travailleur"

To get thing working out, I wrapped up everything in this kind of query :

```
$requete = array();

$i = 0;

foreach($les_cases as $key => $value) {

    $requete[] = array('key'=>$key, 'value' => $le_terme_de_la_recherche['s'], 'compare'=>'IN');
    $i++;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $requete
    )
);
```

When I do a print of my request, it shows something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => enseignant
            [value] => John
            [compare] => IN
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => travailleur
            [value] => John
            [compare] => IN
        )

)
Array
(
    [post_type] => post
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => enseignant
                            [value] => John
                            [compare] => IN
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => travailleur
                            [value] => John
                            [compare] => IN
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

You see that there is alot of [0] in my arrays and I suspect this to create some errors in my query.

After all, should I take compare **LIKE**, **IN** or **=** if I want to be able to select a part of the datas. In exemple, if I wrote John it would be able to give me John Doe.

If some one could help me to manage this puzzle I would be gracefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one extra array in your meta_query.

Instead of doing

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $requete
    )
);
```

try

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'meta_query'        => array_merge( // merge instead of pushing a new array
        array( 'relation' => 'OR' ),    // this must be an array
        $requete
    )
);
```

And make sure your meta keys are correct, of course.
(btw, the [0]'s are just the array keys, you can't have an array without keys).

Comment: It is actually working great for the moment. Thx for the update.